# Ionic2: How to create 3D animations, or how to include Three.js library?

Tags: ionic-framework, three.js, ionic2

Trying out ionic 2 here.

I am trying to create a floating cube inside of an application using ionic 2. The main problem I am having is to include the three.js library and making my custom script of the cube to appear in the app.

Does anyone know how to get things done in ionic 2, or if there are some 3D solutions available for ionic 2?

Answer (score 1):

I did create a simple Ionic2 app that includes a 3d model of the `.stl` format.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/quickies/Ionic3D.poc

[image]

The [main commit](https://github.com/quickies/Ionic3D.poc/commit/108a958f36aabd6f55d35480e649974164a9e483) shows what I include in my `package.json` file and how I include [three.js](https://threejs.org) in my project.